# For a mixed effects model should baseline values be included in the outcome?

Tags: mixed-model

I'm running a linear mixed effects model with group, time, and the interaction between group and time as fixed effects and a random effect for each subject. The outcome was measured at 3 time points. I was just wondering if it would be more appropriate to include the baseline scores in the model as a covariate with the time 2 and 3 scores as the outcome, or include time 1, 2 and 3 scores as the outcome instead.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on your scientific question.